# How to show count of orders in a price range using pandas/matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have an array in Python with prices:

```
price = ['1.10', '9.31', '49.90', '20.10', '12.60', '33.15', '39.77', '0.00', '18.40', '24.45']
```

How do I create a figure or chart which show the data according to price range?

For example I have:
3 items in range 0.00 to 9.99,
2 items in range 10.00 to 19.99,
2 items in range 20.00 to 29.99,
2 items in range 30.00 to 39.99,
1 item in range 40.00 to 49.99,
0 item in range 50.00 to 59.99

**Update:**

[image: histogram]

I tried on histogram and it works but the labels stack together in my X axis.
Btw my list size is quite big, the length is about 11k.

**Update Again:**

Problem solve when I copy paste all the code into a new .py file.

Comment: Take a look at histogram.

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your efforts?

Comment: @G.Anderson Yes I tried on histogram, but it looks weird at the X axis, did I set anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
price = ['1.10', '9.31', '49.90', '20.10', '12.60', '33.15', '39.77', '0.00', '18.40', '24.45']
price = [float(each) for each in price]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(price,bins=5)
```

This will yield:

[image]

Or, if want to specify bin borders explicitly, can do:

```
plt.hist(price,bins=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60])
```

which gives you:

[image]

More info here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html

If want to specify where your `xlabels` are, you can do, with more elements in the `prices` lists:

```
price = [np.random.normal() for x in range(10000)];
plt.hist(price,bins=100)
ax=plt.gca()
valuefrom=-4
valueto=5
step=1.5
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(valuefrom, valueto, step))
```

This gets you:

[image]

`valuefrom` tells it from where to start putting `xtick labels`, `valueto` tells it until which value it should put `xtick labels`, `step` tells it what the gap between these labels should be.

Comment: (HTH, lmk if need more adjustments to the plots)

Comment: Thanks, I tried on histogram and it works but the labels stack together in my X axis (view the attachment at the question).

Comment: Is the size of my list too large? I have about 11k element inside

Comment: Hmmm, right now I am not able to reproduce the problem. Just plotted 100k elements and it works fine. But in some cases this problem did present itself, trying to find out why...

Comment: Updated the answer (please see the end of it)

Comment: Hrmmm, I create a new python file and copy paste all the code to it then the magic happens. It works like a charm and I not sure why